# Building a student subject portfolio selector via google forms and google script

Tags: javascript, forms, google-sheets

Question regarding building a student subject portfolio selector via google forms and google script! For my final year of high school (IB diploma, if anyone's familiar with it) I have to develop a student profiling application as my end computer science project. By "profiling" app I mean an application that would allow the students to select what subjects they are going to study in 11th grade via google forms and the data from these forms would flow to a google sheets which would be accessed by the school's class administrator. The issue here is that I am not sure how to approach the project. The subjects can choose are limited by number and the total hour count, as well as subject category, and I am not too sure how to implement that into forms. The other concern of mine is that I am not sure how the google sheets that take data from forms would be constantly updated. Is there a way to make data from forms stream constantly to sheets? Any help will be more than appreciated as this is a pressing matter for me. To add to that, if this project of mine is successful, the school will actually implement it, so profiling wouldn't be done on paper anymore. Thank you in advance!﻿

P.S. I have no prior experience in javascript, however, I've been doing java and c++ projects for some time now.

Comment: If you have non trivial requirements  and it has to be in spreadsheets it might make more sense to make a web app running in front of the spreadsheet, you could make a form there, that could communicate with the spreadsheet whenever the user does something.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at google forms, while you're editing a form and click on responses, there should be an area to choose where the responses go. E-mail and spreadsheets are options. Then, from the spreadsheets, you can write any kind of script to handle the data as you wish. The Form will automatically update the spreadsheet as responses are entered.